# Identifying manual data entry errors (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm completely new to Python (<1 week), so please excuse me if this question is quite simple:

I'm seeking to identify incorrectly entered data on 15k+ lines. Each row contains multiple columns:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Employee ID (EID)
- Phone Number
- Address, etc.

As the entries are manual, there is a chance information is entered incorrectly. I'm considering pivoting the data, but I don't know if this is the best solution or how to make the pivot table only keep values where e.g. First/Last Name are the same but EIDs are different (sample below).

I've only gotten to the pivot table part so far, would love any input on this! This might not be the best way to do this, so I'm open to any thoughts.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["FirstName", "Surname","EID"],aggfunc=[len])
```

[image: Example output]

My hope is that the pivot could keep only John Doe and Jane Doe and not show John Peters/Jane Clark (since names are the same but EIDs are different). Based on the count, we know that EIDs 1234 and 6789 are likely the correct values, while the others are input errors.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this: `df[df.duplicated(["FirstName" "Surname"])].drop_duplicates('EID')`

Comment: Thanks very much for your time and response. I tried this, and while it helps identify some scenarios, it doesn't narrow it down to only scenarios where one name is used with two EIDs.